# Explode does not split my string because of a special character

Tags: php, unicode, explode

short question:

I want to split a title which looks like this:

```
$text = This is a text • and this too
```

I tried the following:

```
$arry = explode('•',$text);
```

But it cannot find the Bullet symbol... So it just returns me an array with the Text in it. Do i need to convert it into another format, or how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe try: `$arr = explode('•',$text);` ; This code works fine fore me! Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Rizier123 srry, that was a mistake by me. It was already like this. No, i dont get errors. It just doesnt find it in my text.

Comment: The code you provided [works fine](http://ideone.com/hmG2qI), mind the missing quotes and semicolon.

Comment: works for all PHP versions: http://3v4l.org/XJRZA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your encoding, try something like:

```
explode(chr(149), $text);  //for ISO-8859-1
```

Or

```
explode(utf8_encode('•'), $text);  //for UTF-8
```